# Serialization of generic properties

Tags: c#, .net, xml, generics, xml-serialization

Can someone explain to me why this first example will serialize into XML, and the second will throw runtime errors about trying to convert all of the types to each other? If I remove the `XmlElement` attributes from the second example, it will serialize but the XML element name will be wrong ( "Item" instead of the one specified for its type).  The first snippet was generated from the XSD tool using the schema file.

Better yet, is there a way to get this to work? I would much prefer to use generic types that casting to/from objects. It makes for much cleaner code. Explicitly casting objects shows there's a problem in your design.

```
public partial class OAIPMHtype
{
    private object itemsField;

    [XmlElement( "GetRecord", typeof( GetRecordType ) )]
    [XmlElement( "Identify", typeof( IdentifyType ) )]
    [XmlElement( "ListIdentifiers", typeof( ListIdentifiersType ) )]
    [XmlElement( "ListMetadataFormats", typeof( ListMetadataFormatsType ) )]
    [XmlElement( "ListRecords", typeof( ListRecordsType ) )]
    [XmlElement( "ListSets", typeof( ListSetsType ) )]
    [XmlElement( "error", typeof( OAIPMHerrorType ) )]
    public object Item
    {
        get { return this.itemsField; }
        set { this.itemsField = value; }
    }
}
```

This will not serialize.

```
public class OaiPmh<T>
{
    private T itemsField;

    [XmlElement( "GetRecord", typeof( GetRecordType ) )]
    [XmlElement( "Identify", typeof( IdentifyType ) )]
    [XmlElement( "ListIdentifiers", typeof( ListIdentifiersType ) )]
    [XmlElement( "ListMetadataFormats", typeof( ListMetadataFormatsType ) )]
    [XmlElement( "ListRecords", typeof( ListRecordsType ) )]
    [XmlElement( "ListSets", typeof( ListSetsType ) )]
    [XmlElement( "error", typeof( OAIPMHerrorType ) )]
    public T Item
    {
        get { return itemsField; }
        set { itemsField = value; }
    }
}
```

And for further clarification, I have tried specifying all the extra types when creating the `XmlSerializer` object, and that does not help.

This is the exception that's thrown:

```
Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).
error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'ErrorRequest' to 'GetRecordRequest'
error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'ErrorRequest' to 'ListRecordsRequest'
error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'ErrorRequest' to 'IdentityRequest'
error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'ErrorRequest' to 'ListSetsRequest'
error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'ErrorRequest' to 'ListIdentifiersRequest'
error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'ErrorRequest' to 'ListMetadataFormatsRequest'
error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'ListSetsRequest' to 'ErrorRequest'
error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'ListIdentifiersRequest' to 'ErrorRequest'
error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'ListMetadataFormatsRequest' to 'ErrorRequest'
error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'GetRecordRequest' to 'ErrorRequest'
error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'ListRecordsRequest' to 'ErrorRequest'
error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'IdentityRequest' to 'ErrorRequest
```

'

It kind of makes sense with the generic type, seeing how the type is specific bound at compile time. But seeing how it works with an object reference, in my mind it should also work with the generic type.

Comment: Its just another class that contains some int/string properties. Nothing special.

Comment: Update: this will work if you add implicit conversion operators between the various classes. Pain in the buttocks, but it'll work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the [CS0029 compiler error page on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzhh5fx5%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) provides the information you're looking for.

Based on how I read this article, your first example works because there is no conversion happening in your class. Because you explicity are passing around an `Object` there is no conversion that needs to happen and no compiler errors are thrown.

In the second example the type is not known until run time. By specifying multiple XmlElement attributes the compiler thinks that all of these types must be interchangeable. However, since you haven't provided explicit conversions for these the compiler is concerned that a conversion between the two types could be a narrowing conversion and throws the error.

Comment: I agree that that's the problem, but I'm confused why the XmlElement attributes work on the object property. They property define the Xml element in the serialized output.   Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: I suspect that the compiler is creating a class for each XmlElement attribute you're specifying so that at run time, the input data can be serialized in those different forms. I'm not sure that you'll find a solution for it because to enable serializing between types, the compiler needs to know about both types at compile time. ...but I'm not 100% certain.

Comment: All those classes exist, I just didn't add them to the code snippet since they're very simple and extraneous to the example.

Comment: @MonkeyWrench You said "I'm confused why the XmlElement attributes work on the object property". They work on the object property because .NET allocates a specific amount of memory for the `Object` type. When converting between your classes (i.e. GetRecordType, IdentifyType, etc...) .NET has no problem converting because it already knows the size (in memory) of and `Object`, as well as the size of your classes. In the generic example, .NET does not know the size (in memory) of the generic type until run time, so the compiler will need explicit conversions for each class in order to compile.

Comment: continuing from above... This is neccessary because if the generic type passed into your second example was allocated less memory than the type you're converting from, you will lose data in the conversion process.

Comment: Yes, the are all marked serializable.      I tried using a 'where' clause on the class type definition to restrict the generic types, but that of course didn't help. Those are all of varying sizes. Is there a way to do this with generics without implementing the IXmlSerializable interface?

Comment: I suspect the only was to enable this is by coding explicit conversion methods for each type.

Comment: Which doesn't make much sense, considering the classes are too different.

Comment: I'll give you the check for effort, even though you weren't completely correct. Adding implicit cast methods to the classes fixed the problem. Ugly, but it works.

Comment: Experiencing the same problem here - could you clarify how you defined your implicit cast methods, given that the types are 'too different'? In my case it makes the generic property T has a subclass constraint, but it makes no sense to define implicit conversions between the subclasses.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at the [Generics FAQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479858.aspx#bestpractices_topic7) page under the "How Do I Serialize Generic Types" question? It may help you out.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to have different serialized elements for different types is to use `object` or `IXmlSerializable`.

Unfortunatelly the XmlSerializer cannot access non-public properties. So exposing the item as an `object` via a second **public** property allows serialization. I would not use it in real situations, though:

```
[XmlElement("GetRecord", typeof(GetRecordType))]
[XmlElement("Identify", typeof(IdentifyType))]
public object ItemSerializer
{
    get { return this.Item; }
    set { this.Item = (T)value; }
}

[XmlIgnore]
public T Item
//...
```

Comment: But that's exactly what I'm trying to avoid. There should be no need for either using iXmlSerializable or an object property in this scenario.